# When will the Kizumonogatari movie air?

Tags: monogatari-series

From what I have read, Kizumonogatari is a prequel for Bakemonogatari, and the movie is reported to be scheduled for fall 2013.

However, *Monogatari Series: Second Season* was just released this summer (2013), and is still ongoing, so I thought this movie might not be released (again) this fall.

Have they delayed it again?

Comment: related http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18377/why-have-they-been-delaying-kizumonogatari-for-so-long

Comment: **Update:** There's a countdown starting on [the official website](http://www.kizumonogatari-movie.com/). Also, a nonfunctional easter egg when viewing the source.

Comment: I completely removed the information about Hanamonogatari, otherwise, this Q&A will contain 2 separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's #happening!](http://www.kizumonogatari-movie.com/)

On October 4, 2015, [Shaft announced](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-10-03/kizumonogatari-confirmed-as-3-films-starting-on-january-8/.93757) that Kizumonogatari will be released - not as a single film, but as a 3-film series: *Tekketsu*, *Nekketsu*, and *Reiketsu*. These are the three adjectives that Koyomi uses to describe Kiss-Shot, meaning "iron and blood" (as in [Bismarck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_and_Iron_(speech))), "hot-blooded" (emotional, impassioned), and "cold-blooded" (cold, calculating), respectively.

The first movie, *Tekketsu*, premieres on January 8, 2016. There's [a new PV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRdtWrE9bF8) out for it, distinct from [the old PV from back in 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT0uCAwLnjA). Premiere dates for the second and third parts are as yet unknown.

There is actually [a list of theaters in Japan](http://www.toho.co.jp/theater/ve/kizumonogatari/) that will be airing *Tekketsu*, so I think we can rest assured that this is not an elaborate Shaftian trolling effort.

At the time *Tekketsu* was announced, no information about outside-Japan airings of the film was made available. However, Aniplex, which is the producer for the *Monogatari* series, has been fairly good about securing outside-Japan airings for its past films, most notably the three *Madoka* movies. So there is hope.

Answer (score 5):

**This answer is outdated. See [Senshins answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/26405/122).**

There is currently no release date for Kizumonogatari. It was listed for Fall 2013, but was removed, so there's no official release date yet.

Source: [ANN - Kizumonogatari Film Briefly Listed for Fall](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-07-30/kizumonogatari-film-briefly-listed-for-fall) (dated 2013-07-31)